# T-SQL Logic (Where exists one column but not the other)

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need a bit of logical help in writing a query.

Here is the set up.

```
create table main_table 
(
    id varchar(10) not null,
    seq varchar(10) not null
)

insert into main_table (id, seq) 
values ('A1', '1'), ('A1', '2'),
       ('A1', '3'), ('A2', '1'),
       ('A2', '2'), ('A2', '3'),
       ('A3', '1'), ('A3', '2'),
       ('A3', '3');
go

create table sub_table 
(
    id varchar(10) not null,
    seq varchar(10) not null
)

insert into sub_table (id, seq) 
values ('A1', '1'), ('A1', '2'), ('A2', '1');
```

I need a query that returns all records from `main_table` where the `id` of `main_table` matches the `id` of `sub_table`, but `seq` of `main_table` does not match `seq` of `sub_table`.

Expected result is

| id | seq |
| --- | --- |
| A1 | 3 |
| A2 | 2 |
| A2 | 3 |

My attempt

```
select
    a.id, a.seq 
from 
    main_table a
where 
    exists (select 1 from sub_table b
            where a.id = b.id and a.seq != b.seq)
```

What is the right query to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one way ([Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=82f9e0411cffca9f048bfadba6cdc06b))

```
SELECT a.id,
       a.seq
FROM   main_table a
       JOIN sub_table b
         ON a.id = b.id
GROUP  BY a.id,
          a.seq
HAVING MAX(CASE WHEN a.seq = b.seq THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 0
```

Or

```
SELECT a.id,
       a.seq
FROM   main_table a
WHERE  a.id IN (SELECT b.id
                FROM   sub_table b)
       AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                       FROM   sub_table b
                       WHERE  a.id = b.id
                              AND a.seq = b.seq)
```